# Change values in the column

Tags: bash

I've got an issue with my feature_vector.txt file.

It looks like:

```
1,1
2,3
3,3
4,2
etc
```

I am thinking about using AWK to change the values of the second column to zero(0) from the 3rd row to the eg. 20th row.

So the output looks like:

```
1,1
2,3
3,0
4,0
etc.
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
~$ awk -F',' '(NR>3 && NR<6){print $1",0"} (NR<=3||NR>=6)' f
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,0
5,0
6,6
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10
```

using sed:

```
~$ sed '3,6 s/,.*/,0/' f
1,1
2,2
3,0
4,0
5,0
6,0
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>=3 && NR<=20 {$2=0} 1' file
```

- `-F,` sets input field separator as comma
- `-v OFS=,`  will set output field separator as comma
- `NR>=3 && NR<=20` executes a block if current record # is `>= 3 and <= 20`
- `$2=0` will set 2nd field to 0
- `1` is default awk action to print the values